# Launch activity from service when foreground activity has CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS

Tags: android

I'm doing a service able to launch packages and activities from commands sent remotely (no, it's not a virus, it's just for business purposes where my company needs to remotely control devices they have). Based on those commands, I'm able to start activities by using:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Activity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

However, is the foreground activity has CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS as action (I think this is the cause), the activity that I want to start is not started. I don't see any message log...

As I have the device rooted, I've also tried to do a "su -c am start -n <myActivity> but this does not work too.

Any idea?

Comment: From a usability perspective, wouldn't it be better for your users to see a notification instead?

Comment: Imagine that I want to open chrome remotely or a service activity to configure something. I don't know why but if the foreground activity has this "action", I cannot do anything but killing it (or better said, I don't know how to), provided device is rooted. From any other foreground activity that does not have this action, I'm able to start activities or launching packages.

Comment: any activity can intercept a "system dialog" and close it, that may be what you are fighting against.

Comment: Probably off topic, but on my system doing `su -c` requires quotes around the command if the command contains spaces. Or, escape the spaces with backslashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that it closes system dialogs...it was a bad diagnostic I did. The problem is that this activity is reordering tasks and whenever it is paused, it takes the activity manager and put itself on top. This way, no other activity will be on top). I'll modify the other activity so that it "respects" activities thrown by my service when onPause is called. So now I'll try to identify which is the activity that has provoked the pause and if it comes from the service, it won't try to be on top again.

Comment: As you cannot know the reason of the "on pause" from the service I just send a broadcast message that the other activity takes so that it can know that next onpause will be made by the activity